# Deploying django app with gunicorn, Importerror in gunicorn log

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, wsgi, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a django app using gunicorn and nginx based on this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

But im having some trouble getting my gunicorn to work properly,

This is my /etc/init/gunicorn.conf:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid me
setgid www-data


exec myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind  unix:/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

When in my virtualenv i run:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

everything is ok.
But every time i start gunicorn i get this error in my gunicorn error log:

```
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'
```

I checked every possible option, but nothing changed.
Is there anything im missing out?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I added a chdir line before exec:

```
chdir /myproject/myprojectenv
```

Im still getting

```
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'
```

Comment: What's your project name: `'myaproject'` or `'myproject'`?

Comment: It's myproject, there's a typo in there, im gonna correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this manually, you are presumably already in the correct directory, so gunicorn can find the myproject.wsgi module. But when running under upstart, it won't be in that directory, so will have no idea where to find the file.

You can solve this by putting `chdir /path/to/my/virtualenv` before the `exec` line.

Comment: I did as you said, but i'm getting this again:     
ImportError: No module named 'myproject'    , any ideas?

Comment: I changed it again to :     chdir /path/to/myproject    and it started working fine! thanks!

Comment: As Daniel said, with Upstart scripts, you'll need to chdir into the folder where your project resides (so gunicorn can find `myproject`, and specify the abolute path to your virtualenv in the exec section of the script.